# creating app buttons to open the browser

Tags: android, web-applications, layout, button

I attempted to work with a code set for a learning project as shown below however it keeps throwing back errors for R.layout.main. Also, should I add my own own icons or do I simply let the SDK use the defaults?

1)manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity 
            android:name=".todolist"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

2).java

```
package com.tutorial.todolist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class todolist extends Activity {
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clickme);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.anddev.org"));
                    startActivity(myWebLink);
              }
         });
    }
}
```

3).main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_clickme" 
    android:text="Click me..." 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide details of the error that you're getting.

Comment: I assume your main layout file is called main.xml and not just main. Showing your LogCat error would be the greatest help to ppl

Comment: I have removed the [tag:r] tag, because this is reserved for the R statistical processing language, which doesn't seem to be related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing in main.xml
this:

```
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
```

to

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
```

though i am not sure if it will help....

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon (;) in the first line of LinearLayout

`xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name"android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Add this one to your manifest and try again.

Comment: All of this helped, Thanks. I am still looking to resolve two more items. One: I am receiving an error 'classid cannot be resolved or is not a field' at 'R.id.btn_clickme'. Should I have added my own buttons to the res folders or where should I add my buttons? Two: I want to give the user the option of clicking either of two buttons redirecting them to two different websites.

Comment: For second problem: You can open a small dialog on screen like alert dialog. then it ask to which site does user want to go? you can direct user in those buttons' onclick event.